# Visual DOM representation program

Tags: html, css, dom

Is there any program i can use to get a visual DOM representation of a web page? I want to get a result like this here on this picture:
http://bramus.github.io/ria-course-materials/assets/01/simpledom2.png

Comment: Firefox developer edition can get you pretty close

Comment: try to find node modules that does this

Comment: I really don't know what is wrong with my question? Why the downvote and close requests?